# Java Servlet on eclipse: Error instantiating servlet class | ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, servlets

I know this question has been asked a lot but I tried everything and it's still not working for me, hoping someone can help.

I'm trying to run a servlet page on server with eclipse, keeps showing this error:

[image: HTTP Status 500 - Internal Server Error]

Here's my source code:

I've wrote a simple servlet page just to see it running on server:

```
    package main.java.servlet;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class StationsServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public StationsServlet() {

    }

    @Override
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        resp.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter writer = resp.getWriter();
        writer.println("<html>");
        writer.println("<body>");
        writer.println("Hello");
        writer.println("</body></html>");
        writer.flush();
    }

    @Override
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {

    }
}
```

My web.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
    version="3.1">
    <display-name>weather-files-war</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>home.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>stationsServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>main.java.servlet.StationsServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>stationsServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/stations</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

and finally, my folders/modules structure:

[image]

- PS: I created a homepage.jsp and it's working properly on server, the problem is when hitting the servlet class.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I created a new project and a new workspace and just copied modules and classes to the new one and it worked.

I guess it was something to do with eclipse project structure and configurations.

Answer (score 0):

First of all check what the problem with exclamation mark near your StationsServlet.java

Also try to add annotation `@WebServlet(name = "StationsServlet ", value = "/stations")`
before `public class StationsServlet extends HttpServlet {` in your servlet class.
it need to help.

Comment: I already tried the servlet annotations, although when I move my servlet class to the war module it works, i think i have a problem in dependencies or something

Comment: I have copied your code and with annotation it works.

Comment: Try to delete your StationsServlet file, and create it again.

Answer (score -1):

Hope this information is useful for the programmers looking for an answer for this common issue. This answer is based on this question.

Please make sure your servlet class under the following folder
**(Your Project Name)/src/main/java**

Add Annotation to your servlet
**@WebServlet(name="stationsServlet", value = "/stations")**

Your .jsp (homepage.jsp) form should be,

Please follow these steps.

Answer (score -1):

I faced this problem on my M1 MacBook Pro, but might replicate in any M1/M2 devices. The problem was the SQLite library version I was using. The one that worked for me was v3.41.2.1. Remember modifying the build path accordingly if necessary.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).